# "residents of the building" or "the residents of the building"

Tags: articles, definite-article

Shouldn't there be the definite article before "residents of the notorious Sierra Ridge Apartments" in the following sentence?

> **Residents of the notorious Sierra Ridge Apartments** in Northwest Atlanta started to panic Friday after dozens received a notice on their door: they must move out in 30 days. ([Source](http://www.fox5atlanta.com/news/residents-of-embattled-apartments-ordered-to-move))

When I say "residents of this building are not happy", should there always be the definite article before "residents", because apparently the "of" structure specifies which "residents"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The definite article could be used if we are sure that all of the residents started to panic; the definite article would be omitted if we are not sure, or we know that only some residents started to panic.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Article_(grammar)